# Why must a-b and a be on the same side of b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, circles

**Question**: Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be vectors such that the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is $29^\circ,$ and the angle between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b}$ is $84^\circ.$ Find the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b}.$

this is the answer I was given

[image]

this was more what I had in mind

[image]

where a-b is 84° away from b and a is 29° away from b in the other direction. I realize that 84°-29°=55° now, suggesting that a and a-b should be on the same side of b, but I don't understand why.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ represented as vectors, we should try to understand the vectors $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}$. This simply means, follow the vector $\mathbf{a}$, and from that ending point, follow the vector $\mathbf{b}$, but in the opposite direction (since it is negative, or the opposite of, $\mathbf{b}$). The vector $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}$ is the straight-line vector from the original starting point to this ending point.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $a$, $b$ and $a-b$ must have tails at the origin $O(0,0)$.

Refer to the graph:

[image]

To [subtract the two vectors](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Subtract-Vectors#3_To_subtract,_add_the_%22negative%22_of_the_vector), reverse the vector you need to subtract and then add:
$$a-b=a+(-b)$$
Then you must move the vector $a-b$ parallel so that its tail falls on the origin $O(0,0)$.

Hence, you get the three vectors $a, b, a-b$ with the same tail $O(0,0)$ as shown on the graph.

Answer (score -1):

No knowledge of vectors is needed for this problem.

The internal angles of "any" flat-spece triangle add up to $180^\circ .$ The triangle formed by $a, b, a-b$ has two angles adding up to 113. The remaining angle (between $a$ and $a-b$ of the upper triangle) is
$180^\circ-29^\circ-84^\circ=67^\circ$.